# How can i take out value from jquery mobile on and off slider in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I found a code from w3schools for jquery mobile on and off slider input. But i don't know how to take out the value from the input and show it by PHP. Here is the HTML which was on w3schools:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <label for="switch">Flip Toggle Switch:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="switch" id="switch">
        <br>
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me how to take the value from this input in PHP. Thanks in advance

Comment: you need JS to retrieve the value.

Comment: Can you tell me the coding as i don't know much about js

Comment: `$("#switch").val();` is the value of the flipswitch.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['switch']))
{
  echo "On. The user On the switch.";
}
else
{
  echo "Off. The user kept the switch Off.";
}
```

Comment: I see your form action is demoform.asp. Is that right? PHP pages will come with .php extension.

Comment: i am using .php extension only